# selenium selectByVisibleText doesn't trigger on change method

Tags: selenium, combobox, webdriver

I've used selectByVisibleText but the on change method associated to combobox doesn't trigger.

This is the combobox code

```
<form id="j_idt421" class="manageUsersPickerForm ng-pristine ng-valid" style="margin: 20px 0 40px    0;" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/backoffice/manage-merchant-users.xhtml" method="post" name="j_idt421">
<input type="hidden" value="j_idt421" name="j_idt421"/>
<select id="j_idt421:merchantPicker" class="floatLeft mr5" onchange="RichFaces.ajax(this,event,{"parameters"  {"cid":"14256","javax.faces.behavior.event":"change","org.richfaces.ajax.component":"j_idt421:merchantPicker"} ,"sourceId":this} )" size="1" name="j_idt421:merchantPicker"> 
<option value="-1">Select a merchant</option>
<option value="0">automerchant</option>
</select>
<input id="javax.faces.ViewState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="8152201385695173409:3385672536636852427" name="javax.faces.ViewState"/>
</form>
```

And the selenium code:

```
Select droplist = new Select(By.xpath("//select[contains(@id, 'merchantPicker')]"));
droplist.selectByVisibleText("automerchant");
```

After select the value in combobox, the page freeze and doesn't appear the other part.

I'm using chromedriver 2.10

Anyone have the solution for this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by forcing an onchange event to occur using Javascript as below:

```
Select droplist = new Select(By.xpath("//select[contains(@id, 'merchantPicker')]"));
droplist.selectByVisibleText("automerchant");

WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[contains(@id, 'merchantPicker')]"));
JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].onchange()", ele);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't solve my problem. The on change doesn't trigger